# PHP image upload fail

Tags: php

I really need your help. I am trying to upload an image with php code. When I use different .php file with only upload code, it works, but when I try to add to my main code where I have this information which is posted into database.

I have this added and as I said it works with separate code only for upload.

```
form action="core/books-reg.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

This is my main .php code in where I want to make it work. Code starts after !empty(Description). The database takes the name and puts in mysql but there is no file in my folder. any help or other method would be really good.

```
<?php
session_start();

require("dbc.php");

$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$con = $_POST['con'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$prodcode = $_POST['prodcode'];
$isbn = $_POST['isbn'];
$publisher = $_POST['publisher'];
$pages = $_POST['pages'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$course = $_POST['course'];
$module = $_POST['module'];

if(!empty($title))
{
    if(!empty($price))
    {
        if(!empty($prodcode))
        {
            if(!empty($isbn))
            {
                if(!empty($publisher))
                {
                    if(!empty($pages))
                    {
                        if(!empty($description))
                        {
                            if (!isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
                            echo "";
                            }else{
                            $file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
                            $image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
                            $image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

                            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"upload/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);

                            $location="upload/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];             
                            }

                            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `books` (username,title,con,price,prodcode,isbn,publisher,pages,description,image,year,course,module) VALUES('$username','$title','$con','$price','$prodcode','$isbn','$publisher','$pages','$description','$image_name','$year','$course','$module')");
                            header("location: ../add_books.php?feedback=Your book has been put on the books page.");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            header("location: ../add_books.php?feedback=Description field is empty");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        header("location: ../add_books.php?feedback=Pages field is empty");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    header("location: ../add_books.php?feedback=Publisher field is empty");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                header("location: ../add_books.php?feedback=ISBN field is empty");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            header("location: ../add_books.php?feedback=Product code field is empty");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        header("location: ../add_books.php?feedback=Price field is empty");
    }
}
else
{
    header("location: ../add_books.php?feedback=Title field is empty");
}   
?>
```

Comment: the path `upload/` exists? have you write rights on that folder? try `var_dump(is_dir('upload'));`

Comment: yes, as I saidit works when upload code is in separate .php file

Comment: maybe the path from this PHP file is different since you use a relative path

Comment: Everything is fine. As I said, it parses the name to database, but no file is at the upload folder...

Comment: ponciste var_dump(is_dir('upload')); made no difference

Comment: do you mean it returns `true`? btw that it parses the name to the DB has nothing to do with the folder

Comment: Yeah, everything is fine, no errors, but no file in upload folder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u want to place the upload code on same page then firstly you don't need to specify the `action` in the `form` tag.

And check that the path `upload/` is at the correct place exists or not.

Comment: No I want exactly the code to be in different page, because I have details, which should be send to mysql

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"../upload/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);